# How do I export a line shapefile from a network downstream from a point in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, hydrology, geometric-network

I'm using the National Hydrological Dataset's flow lines to trace downstream movement of water is a freshwater diversion from the Mississippi river in Louisiana.  I've gotten the trace to run using the Utility Network Analysis toolbar. I now want to export the trace as a shapefile to create a map.  I've already tried right clicking the flowline layer and exporting but there is no option to export traced features, just those that are selected, all, or those within the viewing frame.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1

[image: Image of study area. Red lines are the downstream traced from the green point]

Comment: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/43472 might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the trace to be selected, rather than being drawn. That is through the analysis> analysis options> results menus of the Utility Network Analysis toolbar (see image).

After that re-compute the trace, and export it regularly.

[image: How to]